# Want to carry a psoriasis cream with me on plane to China -- reasonable?

Tags: air-travel, china, hand-luggage

Here's the deal.

My wife is Chinese and her brother (college age) lives in China. 
I have some cream my grandpa gave me for broken out skin (says IC Triamcinolone 0.5% cream on it). It's worked wonders on me and we want to give her brother a few tubes.

Is either giving him some of my prescription or some of my grandpa's (he has tons of extra tubes he doesn't need) even a remotely good idea? Will it get caught in the scanners?

If I have my own prescription (unsure if I'll break out ever again, let alone in time for our trip next year) will that work?

My wife's brother has been to the doctor on more than one occasion and what

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can expect to be able to bring up to 1 liter onto a plane, in vessels of up to 100ml, carried in a transparent bag. Expect to lose any container over 100ml.

Comment: What about the prescription angle?

Comment: As in that with a prescription you think you might be able to carry more on board? I don't think so. Though, in the end, you can always try to social engineer your way past security, the rules are the rules.

Comment: I'm afraid that w/o a prescription tag on it, they'll toss it summarily.

Comment: If each container is below 100ml, bar individual stupidity, they should not.